# youtube API v3 - rate (like/dislike) comment/commentThread?

Tags: api, youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Quick question - as stated in the title. Is that possible? I thought the following endpoint would be my best shot: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/update, but can't find anything that resembles api call for rating a video, nor did I find any documentation on that for `v3`

If it is, please point me to the http endpoint.

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: Nope. I don't think it's possible, unless something has changed since december.

Answer (score 1):

Partially Yes, You can use that endpoint and specify a value for [snippet.viewerRating](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments#snippet.viewerRating) but as of now it only allows you to specify two values like and none.

> The rating the viewer has given to this comment. Note that this property does not currently identify dislike ratings, though this behavior is subject to change. In the meantime, the property value is like if the viewer has rated the comment positively. The value is none in all other cases, including the user having given the comment a negative rating or not having rated the comment.

Comment: When I try to update comment via google api explorer using the `update` endpoint and passing request body: `{ "id": "z13xcbbrhsuyzlmff23fhxko4nuydhsb204", "kind": "youtube#comment", "snippet": { "viewerRating": "like"  } }` I get `400` response with error message: `The request metadata is invalid.`

Comment: By trial and error I've only managed to like my own comment, and passing `textOriginal` was also required to make it pass.