# Rate comment, that was written by other user using YouTube api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

```
def update_comment(youtube, comment):
  comment['snippet']['viewerRating'] = 'like'
  comment['snippet']['textOriginal'] = 'some text' # Note this is important parameter
  update_result = youtube.comments().update(
    part='snippet',
    body=comment
  ).execute()
```

This code simply updating comment and rate Like, if this comment is mine.

But, if i want rate another comment, Http Error 400 happens.

So, it it able/possible to rate comment, that is written by other user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based from the other SO question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339966/youtube-api-v3-rate-like-dislike-comment-commentthread), the rating of comment can only be done in your own comment and not for the other user.

If you also check the documentation of [`Comments`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments) and [`CommentThreads`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads), there is no way here to achieve the one that you like.

I suggest you to always check the [Revision History](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history) of the YouTube API to know the latest features that you can do with it.

For more information, check also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236975/upvote-youtube-comment-with-api?noredirect=1&lq=1).